# Labels in ECG signal

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I am trying to train ECG signal downloaded from [Physionet](http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/mitdb/) using `LIBSVM` svmtrain, The code is as follows:

> model=svmtrain(labels,features_sparse,'-t 2 -s 0');

I have created features_sparse, but I am confused in making label vector. The only thing I know is that this must be from '.atr' file. But I don't know how to make this matrix/vector.

Any help is appreciated.

NOTE : I used [rddata.m](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/rddata.m) to extract ECG matrix from `100.dat, 100.atr and 100.hea`

Comment: What do you know about the atr file? What did you try to read it?

Comment: Interesting problem. I haven't checked the data yet but it looks like a time series regression problem. I think this question would be more appreciated on http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ since it's regarding your model and not with libsvm as a tool

Comment: @A.Donda atr is annotation file. It consists of labels. (As far as I searched )